# Setting up a subdomain which points to another IP (Apache2)

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain

I'm using Apache, and I'm trying to set up a subdomain for a virtual host, which then points to a server on a different IP address.

So the virtual host is www.example.com, I'd like to set up images.example.com, and point it to 127.0.0.1.

I've consulted some of the answered questions on SO and other sites, but I'm a bit overwhelmed and I don't want to risk wrecking a production site.

Comment: you do this with DNS, not at the webserver level

Comment: also, spend some time creating a test environment. It is time extremely well spent.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I don't know where my head was at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really do want to have `images.example.com` resolve to `127.0.0.1` then the only sensible place to do this is in the hosts file on the server. This is either `/etc/host` (unix like systems) or `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` for windows systems e.g.

```
127.0.0.1    localhost images.example.com
```

Be aware though that 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address and is only accessible from the host on which it is defined.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are absolutely right. As Sam pointed out in a remark to my question, what I was trying to achieve should of course be done on the DNS level. I wasn't thinking. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using DNS (an A record), however if you really want to do it with apache you could define the virtual host then use mod_proxy to pass the request to the other server.
Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html for some example